# When I connect to vps I get an error: Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote in vps- console two files, that work great (test message comes from the client and is displayed by the server script).
Server.py:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
sock.bind(('localhost', 8884))

while True:
    try:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        break
    else:
        client.setblocking(True) 
        result = client.recv(1024)
        client.close()
        print('Message', result.decode('utf-8'))
```

Clien.py:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 8884))
sock.send(b'Test message!')
sock.close()
```

But if I use Client.py from *my home computer*, I get an error:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('145.148.81.8', 8884)) #ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
sock.send(b'Test message from my house!')
sock.close()
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

your server code:

```py
sock.bind(('localhost', 8884))
```

means that the server is only listening for incoming connections on loopback device.

Change that localhost to  `0.0.0.0` and then the server listens on all available network devices.